# Meteor.loginWithToken throwing 403 Login forbidden

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am implementing the login logic my own, instead of using Meteor.loginWithPassword.

After perform all the checking on user credential, i will generate access token from the backend:

[image]

And frontend will use this token to login using Meteor.loginWithToken:

```
Meteor.call('Users.login', username, usernameType, password, (error, result) => {
                console.log(error, result);
                if (!error) {
                    Meteor.loginWithToken(result, (error) => {
                        console.error(stack);
                    });
                } else {
                }
            });
```

But meteor keep throwing error code 403 with the following error message:

```
I20231025-16:28:45.143(8)?   error: errorClass [Error]: Login forbidden [403]
I20231025-16:28:45.143(8)?       at errorClass.Meteor.Error.clone (packages/meteor.js:754:10)
I20231025-16:28:45.143(8)?       at Object.EJSON.clone (packages/ejson/ejson.js:595:14)
I20231025-16:28:45.143(8)?       at packages/ejson/ejson.js:606:22
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at Object.EJSON.clone (packages/ejson/ejson.js:605:13)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at cloneAttemptWithConnection (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1510:31)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:256:16
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at Hook.forEach (packages/callback-hook/hook.js:110:15)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at Hook.each (packages/callback-hook/hook.js:122:17)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at AccountsServer._failedLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:255:30)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at AccountsServer._attemptLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:488:12)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at MethodInvocation.methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:654:23)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1885:12)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:769:19
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1257:12)
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?       at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:767:46 {
I20231025-16:28:45.144(8)?     isClientSafe: true,
```

I was studied the meteor.js code, and found it was error occurred in EJSON.clone() but not sure how to fix it. I had been stucked for so long on this issue. Is anyone have suggestion on it.

Really Appreciated!!!

Solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fixed the issue. It was causes by i didn't return anything in `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt` function. Causes it to always return 403 forbidden. This function expect return value of `true` or `false` to indicate success or reject login attempt.

Thanks.